# Efficient way to organize a sqlite3 db for data acquisition , Single Table with all the readings or a multiple Table per DAQ session?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, database-design, data-acquisition

I am building a data logging software in Python that will store Time,4 temp readings in a sqlite3 database in the following table format.
Data comes over the serial port from external daq,4 values/second and is logged into the the DB by python

| time | temp1 | temp2 | temp3 | temp4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |

One session, may take several readings over several hours and may log 1000 rows or more in each table.

I intend to take multiple sessions lasting several hours of the same above format.

**My question is** should i log all the values to the same table as shown below (For eg 2 independent sessions) (sessions may be more )

| time | temp1 | temp2 | temp3 | temp4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **session1_time0** | session1_temp1 | session1_temp2 | session1_temp3 | session1_temp4 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| session1_time99 | session1_temp1 | session1_temp2 | session1_temp3 | session1_temp4 |
| **SESSION2_time0** | SESSION2_temp1 | SESSION2_temp2 | SESSION2_temp3 | SESSION2_temp4 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| SESSION2_time99 | SESSION2_temp1 | SESSION2_temp2 | SESSION2_temp3 | SESSION2_temp4 |

or

Create multiple tables for each session inside the sqlite3 database.

**Session1 Table inside Database**

| time | temp1 | temp2 | temp3 | temp4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| session1_time0 | session1_temp1 | session1_temp2 | session1_temp3 | session1_temp4 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| session1_time99 | session1_temp1 | session1_temp2 | session1_temp3 | session1_temp4 |

**SESSION2 Table inside same Database**

| time | temp1 | temp2 | temp3 | temp4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SESSION2_time0 | SESSION2_temp1 | SESSION2_temp2 | SESSION2_temp3 | SESSION2_temp4 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| SESSION2_time99 | SESSION2_temp1 | SESSION2_temp2 | SESSION2_temp3 | SESSION2_temp4 |

**SESSION n Table inside same Database**
and so on

**What is the correct way to organize a database in this situation, Single Table containing all the readings or a Table per session?**

- Assume the format of the logging remains the same (time + 4 channels)
- One session happens,values are committed,DB is closed  ,then other
  session happens, No parallal reads or writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One table with session_id with measuremets, but then again just for logging just use csv/json file/s, one per running instance. one file per instance, then if you want publish data , import to real db using copy command (yes , i am thinking postgresql)